# Java - raise Real To Power n^k

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty writing a program to solve this exercise from a Java text book:

> Write a method raiseRealToPower that takes a floating-point value x and an integer
>   k and returns xk. Implement your method so that it can correctly calculate the result
>   when k is negative, using the relationship
>   x^(-k) = 1 / x^k.
>
> Use your method to display a table of values of πk for all values of k from –4 to 4.

I didn't done this part with PI, i know that, if my programs starts to work... this is what i done... tell me please, what is wrong.

```
import acm.program.*;

public class vjezba55 extends ConsoleProgram {

    private static final double PI = 3.14159253;

    public void run() {
        double x = readDouble ("x: ");
        double k = readDouble ("k: ");
        println ("x^k = " + raiseDoublePower(x,k)); 
    }

    /* Method that counts x^k */
    private double raiseDoublePower (double x, double k){
        if (k >= 0) {
            return Math.pow(x, k);
        }
        else {
            double total = 1;
            for (int i= 0; i>k; i--) {
                total = (double) 1 / x;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if u insert x = 2 and k = -3 it gives back 0.5 instead of 0.125.

Comment: Using Math.pow surely counts as cheating here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand the part in the question regarding PI, but your method may be much simpler (according to `using the relationship x^(-k) = 1 / x^k`):

```
private double raiseDoublePower (double x, double k){
    if (k >= 0) {
        return Math.pow(x, k);
    }
    else {
        return 1 /  Math.pow(x, -k);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - why is that?

Comment: @MyByD: Oh, my mistake.  Sorry!

Comment: I'm guessing that he shouldn't be using Math.pow(...) that he should implement this method via simpler arithmetic.  For one Math.pow(...) can handle negatives just fine without having to use 1/... For another why else require him to use an int for the power value?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - That's a good point, but originally he used `Math.pow()` in the `k >= 0` case...

Comment: @MByD: yes, I saw that that is what he did, but to be honest, I don't fully trust him to know what he should be doing (sorry).

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at your loop code.  You are just recalculating `total` from scratch on each iteration, rather than updating the previous result.